# How to run `./gradlew test` using GitHub Actions in a repository that does not have keystore file uploaded?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, github-actions, android-keystore

I have a repository in which I do not commit `/keystores/keystore.properties`. When I run the `./gradlew test` command in GitHub Actions and it tries to build my gradle file once it gets to the line about creating the Signing Config for the Release build it fails with this error:

```
/keystores/keystore.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Is it possible to create a temporary `keystore.properties` file and remove it after the task is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's not way for GitHub Actions to get that file when you don't want to push it. However, you can use [Encrypted Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) instead:

1. Put the content of your keystore.properties file into an [Encrypted Secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets). Name it `KEYSTORE_PROPERTIES`.
2. Add a step prior to your `./gradlew test` step, which writes the content to a local keystore.properties file:

   ```
   # …
   steps:
     # …
     - run: echo ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PROPERTIES }} >> keystore.properties
     - run: ./gradlew test
     # …
   ```
3. Build should work.

Note that GitHub Actions does not output the secrets in the log, but will only output asterisks instead, the `echo` however should still work to put the data into the file.